Closed regular monomorphism and closed subspace
I have read the categorical definition of embedding, which is that of regular monomorphism.  In the case of the category of locally ringed space, is it true that closed subspaces are defined by closed regular monomorphism only?

I'm not sure about the "locally ringed" bit, but any closed subspace $C\subset X$ is the equaliser (regular mono) of its "characteristic map" and the constantly $\bot$ map $X\to\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is the Sierpi'nski space.
